# Least Regression Pattern Recognition Sum Error

Tags: java, arrays, sum, least-squares, pattern-recognition

I am working on a project that requires a pattern recognition program. I will receive a data file with 50000+ data points, and have to recognize if a certain pattern is present. If the sum of the square regression is above a certain value, I have the pattern, otherwise, I keep cycling to the end of the of the file. However, at around datapoint 1000 ~ 3500, the sum settles and does not change. I cannot figure out why it won't change.

```
public class Recognition {
    private static final double[] pattern = {102.0909091,
        ...
            -102};
    private static double[] temp = new double[161];
    private static int[] sums;
    private static final int threshold = 2107270;
    private static Scanner reader;
    private static PrintWriter writer;

    public static int[] rec(int[] array) {
        sums = new int[array.length];
        int[] solution = array;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 161; x++) {
            temp[x] = Math.pow((array[x] - pattern[x]), 2);
            solution[x] = 0;
            sums[x] = sumArray();
        }
        loop:
            for (int x = 161; x < array.length; x++) {
                sum = sumArray();
                if (sum > threshold) {
                    solution[x] = 1;
                    cycleArray();
                    sums[x] = sum;
                    continue loop;
                }
                sums[x] = sum;
                solution[x] = 0;
                cycleArray();
                temp[0] = Math.pow((array[x] - pattern[0]), 2);
            }
        return solution;
    }

    private static int sumArray() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
            sum += temp[x];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static void cycleArray() {
        for (int x = (temp.length - 1); x > 0; x--) {
            temp[x] = temp[x - 1];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args0) throws FileNotFoundException {
        reader = new Scanner(new File("data1.txt");
        writer = new PrintWriter(new File("pattern.txt"));
        int[] data = new int[50000];
        int x = 0;
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            data[x] = reader.nextInt();
            x++;
        }
        int[] solutions = rec(data);
        for (int y = 0; y < solutions.length; y++) {
            writer.printf("%d: %d, Running Sum: %d\n", y + 1, solutions[y], sums[y]);
            System.out.println(solutions[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

For clarification, the pattern length is 161 integers. If the pattern is recognized, then a 1 is outputted, otherwise a 0 is outputted. 
Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Just saying : the `loop` label is pointless here, ad makes the code odd-looking

Comment: I had overlooked some aspects of the problem because you use `temp` in many places (bad practice... should be passed as a parameter instead of having a static). You are doing very expensive stuff with this array like iterating through all of it, shifting all elements, whereas you could instead just use the properties of the sum operator to get the same results in constant time. This would also make your logic much clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my whole idea of it, and I dont get stuck except when i hit the max value

```
public class PatternRecognition {

private  double[] pattern = new double[161];
private double[] temp = new double[161];
private  int[] sums;
private static final int threshold = 2107270;

public int[] rec(int[] array) {
    sums = new int[array.length];
    int[] solution = array;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 161; x++) {
        temp[x] = Math.pow((array[x] - pattern[x]), 2);
        solution[x] = 0;
        sums[x] = sumArray(temp);
    }
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length-temp.length; x++) {
    for (int x2 =0; x2<temp.length ; x2++)
        temp[x2] = Math.pow((array[x+x2] - pattern[x2]), 2);
            sum = sumArray(temp);
            if (sum > threshold)
                solution[x] = 1;
            else solution[x] = 0;
            sums[x] = sum;
        }
    return solution;
}

private int sumArray(double[] temp) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
        sum += temp[x];
    }
    return sum;
}

private void cycleArray() {
    for (int x = (temp.length - 1); x > 0; x--) {
        temp[x] = temp[x - 1];
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args0) {
int[] data = new int[50000];
int x = 0;
while (x<data.length) {
    data[x] = x/2;
    x++;
}
PatternRecognition p=new PatternRecognition();
x=0;
while (x<p.pattern.length) {
    p.pattern[x] = x+1;
    x++;
}
int[] solutions = p.rec(data);
for (int y = 0; y < solutions.length; y++) {
    System.out.printf("%d: %d, Running Sum: %d %d\n", y + 1, solutions[y], p.sums[y], Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(solutions[y]);
}
}

}
```